# Child Selector not working properly (selects selectors that are not direct children)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am not sure why my child selector isn't working properly. In my example, only the direct `<li>` tag should have the red color. But instead, all `<li>` tags are colored red.

This is the jQuery fiddle of my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/5Jf4Y/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>My guess is that both your selectors have the same specificity + the color property is inherited.</s>

The color property is inherited.

Set first the default color for `<li>` elements and apply a different color for the direct children `.courses > ul > li`:

```
.courses ul li { 
    color: Black;
    margin-left: 40px; 
}​

.courses > ul > li { 
    color: #9E002E; 
    font-size: 20px; 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/HaCh5/)**

Comment: Inheritance is the only key player here.

Answer (score 3):

The nested children are inheriting the color from their parents, so the selector wasn't actually matching them. Giving the `li`s a default text color fixes the problem (notice the order of the CSS rule blocks, as it makes a difference).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5Jf4Y/6/

Comment: I looked at your demo and noticed that your `.courses ul li` rule comes after your `.courses > ul > li` rule, causing all the list items to be black in color. I don't know if this is to illustrate the repercussion of getting the order wrong, but it certainly doesn't line up with "fixes the problem" which is what most people are after ;)

Comment: Gah, I hit `Run` instead of `Save` on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Jf4Y/6/. That's probably why it didn't work...